# Text symbols appearing as cross in beamer

Tags: beamer, xetex

I am using Museo Fonts (the case is same with Adobe Garamond Pro) to create beamer presentation but some greek symbols such as ϵ, δ and several others appear as cross-in-a-box.

I have also tried different greek symbols from textgreek package such as \textSigma, \textepsilon but the appearance is same as described above.

Does this mean that the fonts I am using doesn't support these symbols?

Comment: Have you tried with an other font ?

Comment: @JérômeDequeker Yes I have tried with Consolas and it displays text symbols correctly. But not these two fonts.

Comment: So the problem seems to come from the font ...

Comment: A minimal example?